# Trouble interpreting a discontinuity model

Tags: interpretation, regression-discontinuity

[image]

The above picture is an excerpt from a paper I am reading. (Roads and Loans, Review of Financial Studies). I think based on the reporting of the results from the authors, beta1 is their interest. But my question is, why would the authors not include [500-h<pop<500+h] separately as they did with the 1000 threshold?